# OpenSolaris iSCSI target - slow read

Tags: iscsi, opensolaris

We have a new NAS with 6xSAS in RAID10, testing OpenSolaris 2009.6 on it.

A local read/write speed is amazing, about 700/350MB/sec. The network is temporary set up a s a single 1Gbit link, without any link aggregation/jumbo frames. I get 80/60MB/sec read/write over NFS.

When sharing a volume via iSCSI I get 60MB/sec write speed however a read speed is very slow, about 5-10MB/sec. What could cause this? Tried Linux/Windows iSCSI initators, result is the same.

Thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iSCSI performance depends a lot on the quality of your networking equipment. A few considerations:

- Make sure your server and clients
  have high quality network cards,
  preferably with TCP offload, or even
  hardware iSCSI capability.
- Make sure your iSCSI traffic is on a wholly separate network. Ideally it would have its own physical switches, but having its own VLAN works as well.
- Don't cheap out on the switches. Make sure you are using one from a vendor known for performance gear (eg: Cisco, Foundry, HP, etc)
- Use jumbo frames. They can boost iSCSI performance by up to 50% by reducing the TCP/IP overhead

On my home OpenSolaris NAS I briefly tested iSCSI, and the performance from my Windows-based initiator was terrible till I switched to jumbo frames.

Comment: I understand, thanks. But how could it be the problem is only with iSCSI read? I don't say I get a perfect results with iSCSI write/NFS, but they are pretty close to the theoretical values what you could have without a separate VLAN/jumbo frames etc on 1xGBE. The problem is only with iSCSI read and only on OpenSolaris (tested linux-based OpenFiler 2.3, works nice).

I've tried built-in zfs iscsi target (SUNWiscsitgt) as well as COMSTAR variation, result is almost the same. On COMSTAR I've got 15MB/sec

Comment: finally I've found you were right. After replacing a switch everything works nice.

It's strange iSCSI target in OpenSolaris is more "sensitive" to a bad network conditions but it is.